# Design a sequence detector to detect 0110 or 0011

Tags: state-machines, sequence-detector

I need to design a sequence detector which detects 0110 or 0010. If any of this is received, the output is logically correct and gives 1. Here is my attempt so far. I would appreciate some advice because I am not sure if it is correct.

[image]

Comment: What range of numbers are possible?

Comment: How do you mean what range?

Comment: List the invalid numbers.

Comment: What happens at the end of the 4-bit sequence? Is 000110 valid after the 6th bit time or after 000 do you need to wait for a new "start" signal or something before starting again?

Comment: yes, it is valid

Comment: what type of sequence_detector ,is it overlapping or non_overlapping sequence detector you are trying to draw.

Comment: Title and body state inconsistent sequences to recognise. `yes, [000110] is valid` Please don't comment comments asking for clarification or complementary information: edit your post.

Answer (score 1):

This is an overlapping sequence-detector for the required sequences.  I used this website to draw the [FSM](http://ivanzuzak.info/noam/webapps/fsm_simulator/).

[image]

This is the code I have written to draw it:

```
#states
START
SEEN_0
SEEN_00
SEEN_01
SEEN_0x1
SEEN_0011
SEEN_0110
#initial
START
#accepting
START
SEEN_0
SEEN_00
SEEN_01
SEEN_0x1
SEEN_0011
SEEN_0110
#alphabet
input_0
input_1
#transitions
START:input_0>SEEN_0
START:input_1>START
SEEN_00:input_0>SEEN_00
SEEN_00:input_1>SEEN_0x1
SEEN_01:input_0>SEEN_0
SEEN_01:input_1>SEEN_0x1
SEEN_0x1:input_0>SEEN_0110
SEEN_0x1:input_1>SEEN_0011
SEEN_0110:input_0>SEEN_0
SEEN_0110:input_1>SEEN_01
SEEN_0011:input_0>SEEN_0
SEEN_0011:input_1>START
SEEN_0:input_0>SEEN_00
SEEN_0:input_1>SEEN_01
```